# setup ssl and http redirect to https

Tags: redirect, ssl

Hi im hosting my site in bluehost, I have a problem with http to https redirect. I tried to create a redirect in htaccess and I get a redirect loop. When I remove my htaccess redirect and tried to put `https://mysite.com` I think it redirects me to http. But I can't seem to find where did that redirect happens, is it possible that it is because of dns record?

UPDATE:
also how can I put the padlock instead of the blank white paper in the browser url.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Here, we set all visiting browsers to WWW.domainname.ext
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Good luck! I hope this solves your problem.

If there is an A-record on www.yourdomain.com, it will overrule your HTACCESS.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer I have not tried it but yes there is an a record i think.. in 
cname(alias) 
host record is www points to 
 mysite.com

Comment: also I already tried your suggestion..but the redirect loop still persist..I can only think of dns record why it is happening